# Reading from an Input file and writing to an Output file in Java

Tags: java, csv, filereader, filewriter

I am currently in my last week of a Java class and our final project requires us to take make a program read a digit and operator (separated by a comma) from a single cell in an Input CSV file, have the program do the math (starting from whatever number I choose, then have the program write the results into an Output CSV file. I have the code down to a conversion error, but I'm sure that is the least of my worries.  My understanding of Java is rudimentary and I am pretty much failing the class.  I just don't think I have the mind for programming and I have expressed that to the professor.  So hopefully I can do well enough on this final project to bump my grade up.  Needless to say, I am going to steer away from this degree plan immediately.

-Mike

This is what the Prof wants the output to look like:

Add           2      total          2

Add           6      total          8

Subtract     9      total         -1

Multiply    10      total         -10

Number of elements = 4, Total = -10, Average = -2.5

Here is the error:
csvRead2.java:37: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
            number[i] = (Integer.parseInt(value[0])); // Change from a String to an integer.
                                         ^

```
import java.io.*;

public class csvRead2 {
   public static void main(String args[]) {

      String operator[];
      String number[];
      String total;
      int i;

      // The name of the file to open.
      String inputFile = "mathInput.csv";

      // This will reference one line at a time
      String line = null;

      try { // start monitoring code for Exceptions
         // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
         FileReader read = new FileReader("mathInput.csv");
         // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
         BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(read);

         // Assume default encoding.
         FileWriter write = new FileWriter("mathOuput.csv", true); // true for append
         // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
         BufferedWriter buffWrite = new BufferedWriter(write);

         // The name of the file to open.
         String outputFile = "mathOutput.csv";

         while ((line = buffRead.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] value = line.split(",");
            operator[i] = value[1];
            number[i] = (Integer.parseInt(value[0])); // Change from a String to an integer.
            // Determine the operator and do the math operation and write to the output file.
            if (operator[i].equals("+")) { // if statement for addition operator
               total = total + number[i];
               buffWrite.write("Add  " + number[i] + "  total  " + total);
               buffWrite.newLine();
               if (operator[i].equals("-")) { // if statement for subtraction operator
                  total = total + number[i];
                  buffWrite.write("Subtract  " + number[i] + "  total  " + total);
                  buffWrite.newLine();
                  if (operator[i].equals("*")) { // if statement for multiplication operator
                     total = total + number[i];
                     buffWrite.write("Multiply  " + number[i] + "  total  " + total);
                     buffWrite.newLine();
                     if (operator[i].equals("/")) { // if statement for division operator
                        total = total + number[i];
                        buffWrite.write("Divide  " + number[i] + "  total  " + total);
                        buffWrite.newLine();
                        if (operator[i].equals("=")) { // if statement for equals operator
                           buffWrite.newLine();
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         // closing BufferedReader and BufferedWriter
         buffRead.close();
         buffWrite.close();
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException ex) { // will catch if file is not found
         System.out.println( "Unable to open file '" + inputFile + "'");                                                
      }
      catch(IOException ex) // catches read and write errors
      {
         ex.printStackTrace(); // will print read or write error
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to put an int in an Array of Strings (number) ...

Answer (score 1):

1. `String number[]` should be `int number[]`. If you are operating on integers, change the data type to int for respective variables. Strings can't be used for addition of numbers.
2. Even after you fix above exception, you are not flushing the write operation. `buffWrite.flush()` is required to write data into file. Call `flush()` before you call `close()` on bufWrite.

**EDIT:** There are many logical errors and they have been addressed.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CSVRead2 {
 public static void main(String args[]) {

  String operator[] = new String[1];
  int number[] = new int[1];
  int total = 0;
  int i=0;

  // The name of the file to open.
  String inputFile = "mathInput.csv";

  // This will reference one line at a time
  String line = null;

  try { // start monitoring code for Exceptions
     // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
     FileReader read = new FileReader("mathInput.csv");
     // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
     BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(read);

     // Assume default encoding.
     FileWriter write = new FileWriter("mathOuput.csv", true); // true for append
     // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
     BufferedWriter buffWrite = new BufferedWriter(write);

     // The name of the file to open.
     String outputFile = "mathOutput.csv";

     while ((line = buffRead.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] value = line.split(",");
        operator[i] = value[1];
        number[i] = (Integer.parseInt(value[0])); // Change from a String to an integer.
        // Determine the operator and do the math operation and write to the output file.
        if (operator[i].equals("+")) { // if statement for addition operator
           total = total + number[i];
           buffWrite.write("Add  " + number[i] + "  total  " + total);
           buffWrite.newLine();
        }else if (operator[i].equals("-")) { // if statement for subtraction operator
              total = total - number[i];
              buffWrite.write("Subtract  " + number[i] + "  total  " + total);
              buffWrite.newLine();
        }
        else if (operator[i].equals("*")) { // if statement for multiplication operator
                 total = total + number[i];
                 buffWrite.write("Multiply  " + number[i] + "  total  " + total);
                 buffWrite.newLine();
        }
        else if (operator[i].equals("/")) { // if statement for division operator
                    total = total + number[i];
                    buffWrite.write("Divide  " + number[i] + "  total  " + total);
                    buffWrite.newLine();
        }
        else if (operator[i].equals("=")) { // if statement for equals operator
                       buffWrite.newLine();
        }

    }
    buffWrite.flush();   
    // closing BufferedReader and BufferedWriter
    buffRead.close();
    buffWrite.close();
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException ex) { // will catch if file is not found
     System.out.println( "Unable to open file '" + inputFile + "'");                                                
  }
  catch(IOException ex) // catches read and write errors
  {
     ex.printStackTrace(); // will print read or write error
  }
}
}
```

EDIT 2:

mathinput.csv ( no empty lines in the file)

2,+

3,+

9,-

mathOutput.csv

Add  2  total  2

Add  3  total  5

Subtract  9  total  -4

Comment: I am able to run and get output. Run the program as it is without any change

Comment: Logical errors noted. Appreciate the help! The program is compiling, however, I am having an issue running the program now. Input string "+" is referring to the first operator in my mathInput file.  File looks good to me, any reason why it would be giving me this error?  <br> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""+" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) at CSVRead3.main(CSVRead3.java:34) –

Comment: Pass the input as follows in file. Line 1:  2 +  Line 2 : 3 + Line 3: 9 -

Answer (score 0):

First, change the type of *number* array from *String[]* to *int[]*. You are storing an integer into an array of strings, hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`value` is an array of `String` and `number` is also an array of `String`.
Now you're taking a string out of `value` parse it to an integer and try to put it into a string array again!

You could change the type of `String number[]` to `int number[]`!

The same goes for your variable total! Since you store an Integer value in there you should change it's type to `int total`

**EDIT:**

Also i noticed you are chaining the if-blocks! I think you might want to think about that concept again! If you receive a `"-"`, your first if-block (`if (operator[i].equals("+"))`) will result in false and all code in that if-block will not be executed!

Comment: Oh I see, I guess I shouldn't nest them in there.  Just make subsequent if statements right?

Comment: @Mike either that or you could use `else if(...)` statements. But yes, subsequent if statements would work!